# Pyglet with PyGObject

Tags: python, pygobject, pyglet

I'm writing a music program in Python. I need a time line in it. I see that PyGObject has the ability to draw, but I would rather use Pyglet for this. Can Pyglet be used to draw on GTK drawing area or some similar widget?

Answer (score 0):

All normal drawing in Gtk is handled by Cairo. Gtk 3.16 did add [GtkGLArea](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGLArea.html) though which can be drawn on using OpenGL. That said I don't know the quality of the Python bindings for GtkGLArea nor do I know if pyglet can easily work for that usage (I suspect not).